# Replace all instances with REGEXP_REPLACE in PLSQL

Tags: regex, plsql

I've been trying to replace all text surrounding the keyword *POSTPONE* in a given string using REGEXP_REPLACE in PLSQL.

In instances where there is two *POSTPONE* notes adjacent to one another, only the frist instance is being replaced.

Below is the example I've been working on

```
CROWHURA_POSTPONE_26/03/2015_Postpone_1 30/03/2015 00:00:00~CAMERONR_POSTPONE_30/03/2015_Postpone_1 04/04/2015 00:00:00~CAMERONR_NOTES_30/03/2015_waiting on sr results~CHINGD_POSTPONE_04/04/2015_Postpone_1 07/04/2015 00:00:00
```

I want only the text related to the __NOTE_

```
#CAMERONR_NOTES_30/03/2015_waiting on sr results#
```

The REGEXP I've been using is this:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(q.comments,'(~|^).{0,10}_POSTPONE_.{1,42}(~|$)','# ')
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT:
Further examples, that the replace needs to work for:
For each of these, I want any and all _note_ related text

```
VANHOOYJ_NOTES_27/03/2015_Site switching out ~VANHOOYJ_POSTPONE_27/03/2015_Postpone_1 03/04/2015 00:00:00
FABISHD_POSTPONE_31/03/2015_Postpone_1 06/04/2015 00:00:00
FABISHD_NOTES_31/03/2015_GE enquiry~FABISHD_POSTPONE_31/03/2015_Postpone_1 06/04/2015 00:00:00
CAMERONR_NOTES_31/03/2015_booked sr ~CAMERONR_POSTPONE_31/03/2015_Postpone_1 05/04/2015 00:00:00
FABISHD_POSTPONE_01/04/2015_Postpone_1 06/04/2015 00:00:00
CHINGD_POSTPONE_01/04/2015_Postpone_1 03/04/2015 00:00:00~CHINGD_POSTPONE_04/04/2015_Postpone_1 07/04/2015 00:00:00
FABISHD_NOTES_31/03/2015_GE enquiry~FABISHD_POSTPONE_31/03/2015_Postpone_1 06/04/2015 00:00:00
CHINGD_NOTES_01/04/2015_waiting on switching~CHINGD_POSTPONE_01/04/2015_Postpone_1 06/04/2015 00:00:00
FABISHD_NOTES_19/03/2015_Needs to be completed by switching~FABISHD_POSTPONE_19/03/2015_Postpone_1 26/03/2015 00:00:00~FABISHD_NOTES_26/03/2015_Switching~FABISHD_POSTPONE_26/03/2015_Postpone_1 30/03/2015 00:00:00~CHINGD_POSTPONE_30/03/2015_Postpone_1 06/04/2015 00:00:00
CHINGD_NOTES_27/03/2015_GEN2360163 to confirm read~CHINGD_POSTPONE_27/03/2015_Postpone_1 01/04/2015 00:00:00~CHINGD_POSTPONE_29/03/2015_Postpone_1 02/04/2015 00:00:00~CHINGD_POSTPONE_04/04/2015_Postpone_1 07/04/2015 00:00:00
CHINGD_POSTPONE_29/03/2015_Postpone_1 02/04/2015 00:00:00~CHINGD_POSTPONE_04/04/2015_Postpone_1 07/04/2015 00:00:00
CHINGD_NOTES_01/04/2015_waiting on switching~CHINGD_POSTPONE_01/04/2015_Postpone_1 06/04/2015 00:00:00
FABISHD_NOTES_30/03/2015_Unsure where to credit units to.~FABISHD_POSTPONE_30/03/2015_Postpone_1 31/03/2015 00:00:00~CAMERONR_POSTPONE_31/03/2015_Postpone_1 05/04/2015 00:00:00
```

Comment: Works for you? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb/3139

Comment: Yes, thanks, that works for that example. I've added other examples that this also needs to work for.

Comment: And when there isn't a `_notes_` related?

Comment: Null preferably. However the current SQL leaves those fields with #, which is fine for my purpose.

Comment: When there is two ocurrences you want then 2 or just the first?

Comment: As far as I've got: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3a47b/12 it is late night here and tomorrow I will have a look again.

Comment: I want all notes to come through.
Thanks Jorge, i'll see what I can do in the mean time.

Comment: Think I've got it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/40d23/1. I'll test more tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3a47b/26)

**Query **:

```
select val,
regexp_replace(val, '(~?([^~]+_NOTES_[^~]+)~?)|(.)','#\2#') x,  --keeps the notes part and replaces everything esle with #
regexp_replace(regexp_replace(val, '(~?([^~]+_NOTES_[^~]+)~?)|(.)','#\2#'),'#{2,}','#') y  --removes consecutive #s
from
test t
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3a47b/26/0)**:

```
|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     VAL |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      X |                                                                                                Y |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|                                                                                                                                                                      VANHOOYJ_NOTES_27/03/2015_Site switching out ~VANHOOYJ_POSTPONE_27 |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         #VANHOOYJ_NOTES_27/03/2015_Site switching out ################################################################################ |                                                  #VANHOOYJ_NOTES_27/03/2015_Site switching out # |
|                                                                                                                                                                                                                     FABISHD_POSTPONE_31 |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          ############################################################################# |                                                                                                # |
|                                                                                                                                                                                 FABISHD_NOTES_31/03/2015_GE enquiry~FABISHD_POSTPONE_31 |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     #FABISHD_NOTES_31/03/2015_GE enquiry############################################################################## |                                                            #FABISHD_NOTES_31/03/2015_GE enquiry# |
|                                                                                                                                                                               CAMERONR_NOTES_31/03/2015_booked sr ~CAMERONR_POSTPONE_31 |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  #CAMERONR_NOTES_31/03/2015_booked sr ################################################################################ |                                                           #CAMERONR_NOTES_31/03/2015_booked sr # |
|                                                                                                                                                                                                                     FABISHD_POSTPONE_01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          ############################################################################# |                                                                                                # |
|                                                                                                                                                            CHINGD_POSTPONE_01/04/2015_Postpone_1 03/04/2015 00:00:00~CHINGD_POSTPONE_04 |                                                                                                                                                                                                                        ############################################################################################################################################################################################### |                                                                                                # |
|                                                                                                                                                                                 FABISHD_NOTES_31/03/2015_GE enquiry~FABISHD_POSTPONE_31 |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     #FABISHD_NOTES_31/03/2015_GE enquiry############################################################################## |                                                            #FABISHD_NOTES_31/03/2015_GE enquiry# |
|                                                                                                                                                                         CHINGD_NOTES_01/04/2015_waiting on switching~CHINGD_POSTPONE_01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              #CHINGD_NOTES_01/04/2015_waiting on switching############################################################################ |                                                   #CHINGD_NOTES_01/04/2015_waiting on switching# |
| FABISHD_NOTES_19/03/2015_Needs to be completed by switching~FABISHD_POSTPONE_19/03/2015_Postpone_1 26/03/2015 00:00:00~FABISHD_NOTES_26/03/2015_Switching~FABISHD_POSTPONE_26/03/2015_Postpone_1 30/03/2015 00:00:00~CHINGD_POSTPONE_30 | #FABISHD_NOTES_19/03/2015_Needs to be completed by switching######################################################################################################################FABISHD_NOTES_26/03/2015_Switching################################################################################################################################################################################################## | #FABISHD_NOTES_19/03/2015_Needs to be completed by switching#FABISHD_NOTES_26/03/2015_Switching# |
|                                               CHINGD_NOTES_27/03/2015_GEN2360163 to confirm read~CHINGD_POSTPONE_27/03/2015_Postpone_1 01/04/2015 00:00:00~CHINGD_POSTPONE_29/03/2015_Postpone_1 02/04/2015 00:00:00~CHINGD_POSTPONE_04 |                                                #CHINGD_NOTES_27/03/2015_GEN2360163 to confirm read#################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################### |                                             #CHINGD_NOTES_27/03/2015_GEN2360163 to confirm read# |
|                                                                                                                                                            CHINGD_POSTPONE_29/03/2015_Postpone_1 02/04/2015 00:00:00~CHINGD_POSTPONE_04 |                                                                                                                                                                                                                        ############################################################################################################################################################################################### |                                                                                                # |
|                                                                                                                                                                         CHINGD_NOTES_01/04/2015_waiting on switching~CHINGD_POSTPONE_01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              #CHINGD_NOTES_01/04/2015_waiting on switching############################################################################ |                                                   #CHINGD_NOTES_01/04/2015_waiting on switching# |
|                                                                                               FABISHD_NOTES_30/03/2015_Unsure where to credit units to.~FABISHD_POSTPONE_30/03/2015_Postpone_1 31/03/2015 00:00:00~CAMERONR_POSTPONE_31 |                                                                                                                                                       #FABISHD_NOTES_30/03/2015_Unsure where to credit units to.###################################################################################################################################################################################################### |                                      #FABISHD_NOTES_30/03/2015_Unsure where to credit units to.# |
```

Thanks to @Jorge Campos for the sqlfiddle.